# How do i get table1 userid to replace with table2 username?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

TABLE-1

```
INSERT INTO `r_store`.`tb_user`(`id`,`username`,`password`,`role`,`actions`)
VALUES(1,'SSP','123','ADMIN',1),(2,'RRP','123','ADMIN',1);
```

SELECT * FROM r_store.tb_user;

```
'1','SSP','123','ADMIN','1'
'2','RRP','123','ADMIN','1'
```

TABLE-2

```
INSERT INTO `r_store`.`tb_main_product`(`shortname`,`mainproduct`,`tb_user_id`)
VALUES('RR','RAJ',1),('LK','LAKS',2),('DY','DIYA',5),('DY','DIYA',3);
```

SELECT * FROM r_store.tb_main_product;

```
'21','RR','RAJ','1'
'22','LK','LAKS','2'
'23','DY','DIYA','1'
'24','DY','DIYA','2'
'25','RR','RAJ','1'
'26','LK','LAKS','2'
'27','DY','DIYA','1'
'28','DY','DIYA','2'
```

I need like

```
'21','RR','RAJ','SSP'
'22','LK','LAKS','RRP'
'23','DY','DIYA','SSP'
'24','DY','DIYA','RRP'
```

i'm tried these queries

```
SELECT shortname,mainproduct,username FROM tb_main_product left join  tb_user USING (id);
SELECT shortname,mainproduct,username FROM tb_main_product join  tb_user USING (id);
```

its not working please help mee

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine the correct columns

```
SELECT 
    shortname, mainproduct, username
FROM
    tb_main_product tmp
        LEFT JOIN
    tb_user tu ON tu.id = tmp.tb_user_id
```

Comment: 'RR','RAJ','SSP'
'LK','LAKS','RRP'
'DY','DIYA',NULL
'DY','DIYA',NULL
'RR','RAJ','SSP'
'LK','LAKS','RRP'
'DY','DIYA',NULL
'DY','DIYA',NULL

Comment: yes that is wha a left join makes, it combines both tabkes, even when tb_main_product  has no corresponding patner, please when you comment explain in detail your problem